# How to concatenate all the strings in an array to a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that extract email addresses from a variant and I would like to put each email address to a cell but I'm always getting type mismatch error when I use something like

```
Range("A9").Value = Range("A9").Value & ExtractEmailAddresses(Contact) & "; "
```

Currently, the cell value is being updated by the last element in my array.. what I want is to concatenate each array element instead like "test1@gmail.com; test2@gmail.com". Can someone help me with this, thanks!

Here's my sample code:

```
 Dim LArray() As String
 Dim CCArray() As String
 Dim Contact As Variant
 Dim strCC As String
 
 LArray = splitLineBreaks(Range("A4").Value)

     If IsNull(LArray) = False Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(LArray)
           If InStr(LArray(i), "CC:") Then
                strCC = LArray(i)                
                CCArray = Split(strCC, ">")
                
                For Each Contact In CCArray
                Range("A9").Value = Range("A9").Value & ExtractEmailAddresses(Contact)
                Next
                

            End If
        Next i
    End If
```

Extract Email Address function:

```
Public Function ExtractEmailAddresses(ByVal sInput As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oRegEx                As Object
    Dim oMatches              As Object
    Dim oMatch                As Object
    Dim sEmail                As String
 
    If Not IsNull(sInput) Then
        Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With oRegEx
            'Basic pattern
            '.Pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"
            'More advanced pattern that allow accented characters
            .Pattern = "([a-zA-ZF0-9\u00C0-\u017F._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u017F_-]+)"
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .MultiLine = True
            Set oMatches = .Execute(sInput)
        End With
        For Each oMatch In oMatches
            sEmail = oMatch.Value & "," & sEmail
        Next oMatch
        If Right(sEmail, 1) = "," Then sEmail = Left(sEmail, Len(sEmail) - 1)
 
        ExtractEmailAddresses = Split(sEmail, ",")    'Return an array of email addresses extracted from sInput
    Else
        ExtractEmailAddresses = Null
    End If
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oMatch Is Nothing Then Set oMatch = Nothing
    If Not oMatches Is Nothing Then Set oMatches = Nothing
    If Not oRegEx Is Nothing Then Set oRegEx = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: ExtractEmailAddresses" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function

Function splitLineBreaks(ByVal str As String) As Variant
    str = Replace(str, vbCrLf, vbCr)
    str = Replace(str, vbLf, vbCr)
    splitLineBreaks = Split(str, vbCr)
End Function
```

Sample data from A4

[image]

Comment: It's a function for extracting the email address from Contact @BigBen

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data so we can see what you actually have

Comment: I have a cell in excel and it's containing an email body from Outlook.. I have to get the "TO", "CC" and "From" from previous email which is in the email body so I thought of using split and delimiter.. it works for TO and From when I'm using this function since it always has one email address but for CC it has two or more that's why I use split and delimiter again to get each addresses from CC but I'm unable to concatenate the results in a cell. @findwindow

Comment: It's just a sample data but I updated the post @BigBen

Comment: Not all the emails, just the CC email addresses.. I'm already looping it.. I just need to concatenate each value/element from the array into the cell with a specific format like "test1@gmail.com; test2@gmail.com" but I don't know how @findwindow

Comment: I'm not sure if it's applicable since the number of addresses varies from time to time, it's not always two. @findwindow

Comment: I don't know what you are asking anymore. If ccarray gives you the CC emails and your function gives you the to and from, loop through both separately and combine them into a string that you then drop into cell? If ccarray doesn't give you what you want, I can't do regex so afraid I can't help.

Comment: I apologize I'm pertaining only to CC email addresses that's being vary from time to time.. I just can't get the idea of looping them separately. I am looping the TO, From and CC separately already. Above code is only for CC in which I'm having an issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't see a loop for ExtractEmailAddresses but maybe there's more code.